# Как получить таблицы, в которых есть значение true

Tags: sql

Есть postgress таблица со значениями:

```
[
   { 
     a: true,
     b: false,
     c: true
   }
]
```

Можно ли как-то через sql достать только те столбцы, где значение = true, без перебора каждого столбца?
т.е. не так:

```
select * from table
where table.a(b/c) = true
```

Comment: `select * from table where a or b or c`

Comment: *достать только те столбцы* Если речь о том, что в разных записях будет разное количество полей - то так не бывает. Если речь о том, что удалить из JSON ключи, значения которых не true, и вернуть остаток как JSON - то да, можно.

Comment: А если в таблице гарантированно будет только одна запись, можно ли такое сделать?